Cross program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
This is the smart contract code and its test case where the error as in the title occurs (Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account.)
Error

Code:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token::{self, Mint, Token, TokenAccount},
};

declare_id!("HoKwJaMW38b7ZpCyrh9sgQMnR4VACuR3d4A9Bq7A9EdL");


const MIN_NAME: usize = 50;
const MAX_AGE: u8 = 130;


#[program]
pub mod student_manage {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize_token_mint(_ctx: Context<InitializeMint>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Token mint initialized");
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn create_student(ctx: Context<Student>, name: String, age: u8) -> Result<()> {

        require!(name.len() <= MIN_NAME, StudentError::InvalidName);
        require!(age <= MAX_AGE, StudentError::InvalidAge);

        msg!("Created student success!");

        let student = &mut ctx.accounts.student;

        student.name = name;
        student.age = age;


        let seeds = &[
            "mint".as_bytes(), 
            &[ctx.bumps.mint]
        ];
        let signer = [&seeds[..]];

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            token::MintTo {
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            },
            &signer,
        );

        token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, 10000000)?;
        msg!("Minted Tokens");


        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(name:String)]
pub struct Student<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        space = 8 + StudentState::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds = [ name.as_bytes()  , payer.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub student: Account<'info, StudentState>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    #[account(seeds = ["mint".as_bytes()], bump)]
    pub mint: Account<'info,Mint>,

    #[account(init, 
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = payer
    )]
    pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]

pub struct StudentState {

    pub student_key:Pubkey,

    #[max_len(50)]
    pub name: String,

    #[max_len(3)]
    pub age: u8,
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeMint<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = ["mint".as_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = 6,
        mint::authority = payer,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[error_code]
enum StudentError {
    #[msg("Name is too long ")]
    InvalidName,
    #[msg("Age is too highest")]
    InvalidAge
}

Test:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { StudentManage } from "../target/types/student_manage";

import { getAssociatedTokenAddress } from "@solana/spl-token";

import { expect } from "chai";

describe("student_manage", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.StudentManage as Program<StudentManage>;

  const student = {
    name: "kadamato",
    age: 20,
  };

  it("Initializes the reward token", async () => {
    const tx = await program.methods.initializeTokenMint().rpc();
  });

  it("create student", async () => {
    const [studentPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from(student.name), provider.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );

    //  mint reward
    const [mint] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("mint")],
      program.programId
    );

      //  token account
    const tokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mint,
      provider.wallet.publicKey
    );
    const tx = await program.methods
      .createStudent(student.name, student.age)
      .accountsPartial({
        student: studentPDA,
        mint: mint,
        tokenAccount: tokenAccount,
        payer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc();
    console.log(tx);

  });
});


In your InitializeMint struct, you are setting the payer as the authority
    #[account(
        // -- snip
        mint::authority = payer,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

But are using a different one when doing the transfer which is causing the error
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            token::MintTo {
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: // change this to the proper authority address and sign the tx with it 
            },
            &signer,
        );

You might need a new mint_authority PDA and assign it the authority of the mint, which you can use to sign the transfer instruction

Thank you so much, the problem solved
